# Why is my GUI content flickering?

Tags: c#, user-interface

I want to build a window which contains a simple square which is moving. It works so far but the rectangle is flickering and I don't know why. How can I fix this problem. I just want to learn how to use C# for making games

This is my Program.cs

```
        static void Main()
        {
            Form1 myForm = new Form1();

            while (true)
            {
                myForm.UpdateData();

                myForm.Invalidate();
                myForm.Update();
                myForm.Refresh();

                myForm.Show();
                Thread.Sleep(15);
            }
        }
```

This was my Program.cs

And this is my Form1.cs

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Text = "2D Grafik mit C# - Beispiel 1";

            DoubleBuffered = true;

            g = this.CreateGraphics();
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            xPos = 50;
            yPos = 50;
        }

        public void UpdateData()
        {
            xPos += 1;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), xPos, yPos, 50, 50);
        }
```

I can't imagine what this problem is caused by

Can anyone help me?

Thanks for help

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-reduce-graphics-flicker-with-double-buffering-for-forms-and-controls

Comment: Considering you "just want to learn how to use C# for making games", winforms is not the best use of your time.  Unity is a better choice:  https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/scripting

Comment: Basic rule: Never cache a Graphics object. Use e.Graphics One Invalidate is enough, all the other calls in your main loop are wrong. It will stop flickering but will still be jumpy because the refresh is not in sync with the monitor. A winforms limit, which is rather hard to overcome.

Comment: WinForms is based on very old Win32 API, namely its GDI part. It was never intended for frequent refreshing and has no warranty at which time actual visualization to be redrawn. As a result, GDI is for very basic games like Minesweeper.

Comment: In addition you send the GUI thread to sleep most of the time, probably making the 'game' unresponsive. This is usually avoid with a Timer; in the Tick do Invalidate the playing field..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Program.cs`, you don't need to show the form in every iterations, and you don't need the refresh:

```
static void Main()
{
    Form1 myForm = new Form1();
    myForm.Show();

    while (true)
    {
        myForm.UpdateData();

        myForm.Invalidate();
        myForm.Update();

        Thread.Sleep(15);
    }
}
```

And if you change in your `Form1.cs` the `OnPaint` method to this, the flicker will gone:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), xPos, yPos, 50, 50);
}
```

But, as the others noted, I also think so, that WindowsForms is not the best choice for creating a game.